# Combining knockout with sammyjs/pathjs and jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js, singlepage, sammy.js, path.js

I'm trying to combine some of JS libraries to create a mobile SPA website. I'm working with knockoutJS that misses routing engine so I take it from SammyJS or PathJS (haven't decided yet). And I'd like to use jQuery Mobile to get the controls and the mobile design from it.

The thing is that whenever I include the jquery mobile js file into my page the routing engine stops working. Actually it does work, but the `window.location.hash` get changed not only by me but with jquery mobile itself.

So here is how the code looks like:
in the html file I got a div that I binded to a template

```js
(function ($) {
infuser.defaults.templateUrl = "templates";
console.log('just before pageinit');
$(document).bind('pagecreate', function () {
    // disable autoInit so we can navigate to bookmarked hash url
    $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;

    // let PathJS handle navigation
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});

$(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function (e, data) {
    var to = data.toPage;
    if (typeof to === 'string') {
       /* var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(to);
        to = u.hash || '#' + u.pathname;
        // manually set hash so PathJS will be triggered
        location.hash = to;
        // prevent JQM from handling navigation*/
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});
$(document).bind('pagechange', function (e, data) {
});

var Model = function () {
    this.items = ko.observable(null);
    this.chosenItemData = ko.observable();
    this.state = ko.observable('items');

    this.goToItemDetails = function (item) {
        location.hash = '/details/' + item.id;
    };
};
window.currentModel = new Model();
ko.applyBindings(window.currentModel);

Path.map('#home').to(function () {
    currentModel.state(window.templates.items);
    currentModel.items(window.dummyData);
});
Path.map('#home/details/:id').to(function () {
    var self = this;
    $(currentModel.items()).each(function (index, item) {
        if (item.id.toString() == self.params['id']) {
            currentModel.chosenItemData(item);
            currentModel.state(window.templates.itemDetail);
        }
    });
});

Path.root('#home');

$(function () {
    Path.listen();
})
})(jQuery);
```

Now, you can see that  `$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;` is set to false so the jquery mobile should not listen or react to hash changes whatsoever.

But!
lets say I move from localhost/sammy/#home to localhost/sammy/#home/detail/1
the hash change happens and changes right away to  localhost/sammy/home/detail/1
for some reason the hash itself is ommited and the route doesn't get executed.

I sorry if I didnt explain myself better. I'm working on publishing it on a server for everyone to be able to look at it, but, unfortunately it takes time.

Meanwhile, if anyone has any idea what i can do to fix this it will be awesome!

Comment: While not a direct answer to your question, I did share some of my experiences of combining Knockout and jQueryMobile http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/10/integrating-knockout-and-jquerymobile/ the integration is not without some pain!

Comment: by debugging jquery mobile I found another mobile parameter: $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false; this disabled the pagechage events, but the hash symbol still gets omitted.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently (and it's written in the jQuery Mobile website the "initmobile" event fires as the script for jquery mobile it attached. To be able attach the event the following lines should be included **before** the jQuery Mobile script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
});
```

then the onchangehash event in jquery mobile will be disabled.